# Calculate azimuth and elevation angles

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have two frames: /parent and /child. I can use tf:lookuptransform to find the transformation between two frames.
Now, I want to find the azimuth and elevation angles in spherical coordinate between two frames. Do ROS have any available function to do something like that?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229797/calculate-azimuth-and-elevation-angles/) by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2016-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-03-21**:
How would you define the azimuth and elevation angles "between two frames"? They give you 2DOF and a generic 3D transformation would need 6DOF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, to my knowledge ROS doesn't make those methods available.

You need to better define what *between two frames* means, though. Assuming you can treat Frame1 as the origin (that is, position `(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)` and orientation `(x,y,z,w)=(0,0,0,1)`), calculating the azimuth/elevation to another frame can be accomplished using only Frame2's relative-to-Frame1 `(x2,y2,z2)` location:

```
magnitude = sqrt((x2*x2) + (y2*y2) + (z2*z2));
azimuth   = atan2(y2, x2);
elevation = asin(z2 / magnitude);
```

Note that angles should be normalized to `-M_PI <= val < M_PI`.

If you're going to be working with spherical coordinates, two sites I've found invaluable are [Aviation Formulary](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm) and [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1